# Https client with authorization in C#

Tags: c#, ssl, https, http-headers, authorization

I'm trying to create a https client in C#.

I had HTTP client which worked fine and I changed it to work with HTTPS. But unfortunately there is something wrong with the authorization (the server uses OAuth 2).

My program sends a request to a server and gets the token. But it can't get or send any data from the server.

The server works fine with other clients, so it's not its fault.

This is a piece of code which causes the problem. I know that, because when I comment authorization on the server, the data is send (everything is fine).

```
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
        "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
         string.Format("Authorization: {0}", token))));
```

This is the whole function, which should send data:

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
X509Certificate certificate = GetMyX509Certificate();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

string uri = "https://192.168.0.10:8443/data";

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
     string.Format("Authorization: {0}", token))));

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);

var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters["name"] = name;
parameters["surname"] = surname;

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(parameters);

System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
var response = client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

Console.WriteLine((response.StatusCode.ToString()));
string resultContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
```

I guess I'm missing something in the header but can't find any information in the documentation about that.
It's a difficult issue so any advice will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be including the HTTP header name (`"Authorization: "`) in the parameter of the `AuthenticationHeaderValue`. Setting the `Authorization` property will add the header to the request.

Additionally for OAuth 2, you probably want to be using `"Bearer"` as the scheme and not encoding `token` with base64.

Something like this should therefore work:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```